# How to validate the following phone numbers?

Tags: jquery, regex, phone-number

These numbers are acceptable:

(0123) 456789

(01 23) 45 67-89

0123/456789

+49(0)123-456789

How my pattern should look like?
/^[0-9]+$/;...

I don't know exactly how to integrate the addition symbol , "space" and so on...

Comment: I would suggest learning regexes or hire someone who knows it. Then come with the patterns you've tried if they fail. From where I see it, I would use different patterns for each validation, cause the strings are very different one from another.

Answer (score 0):

/^+?([0-9]{2}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

but you should definitely go over http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html and modify this regex for your needs

Comment: this is not working for me... when I am using this pattern, I even cannot start my formular with the including phone number field (it is laying in an overlay)

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if you stripped out everything that isn't a number then validate it based on that. So first.

```
var barePhoneNumber = number.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Then, a pretty simple if test. 12 characters are ok if it starts with 49, otherwise, only 10.

```
var validLength = basePhoneNumber.substr(0, 2) === '49' ? 12 : 10;
if( basePhoneNumber.length === validLength )){ 
   // It's valid! 
}
```